# Como enviar varias veces los datos del mismo fomulario sin recargar o borrar los datos?

Tags: php

Enlace del proyecto: https://we.tl/t-TbR1iF8fvP

Usuario: Cristhian

Pass: 123

Debo reportar las horas que un trabajador utiliza para realizar una tarea, tengo 7 trabajadores entonces duplico el formulario donde reporto las horas, pero al enviar uno se borra la informacion de los otros formularios porque recarga la pagina, por ahora solo lo tengo duplicado una vez osea que puedo reportar 2

Como puedo dar recompensa a esta pregunta?

Comment: te refieres a éste formulario? 
<form method="POST" action="action/user_save_report.php">

Comment: Si ese es el formulario que duplicó y quiero guardar diferentes veces sin que me borre los datos de los demas formulario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero me nace una duda, vas a crear un formulario por cada colaborador?, éso debe ser dinámico como vas a hacer en el futuro cuando la cantidad de colaboradores crezca?.

Yendo al problema como tal, necesitas hacer uso de ajax para enviar el formulario sin hacer el submit. Te dejo un enlace de cómo se hace:

[submit form ajax jquery](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form)

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias, y el numero de trabajadores es fijo en 7 personas

Comment: Aummm me parece que vas a tener problemas en el futuro con eso. Tu o quien tenga que hacerle mantenimiento a la app en el futuro :-/. Espero que no jaja! Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre variables de sesión para cada usuario y en un momento dado grabas el tiempo de entrada y salida en una base de datos.

Comment: Hay una sola persona reportando, osea que los trabajadores solo le dicen que ya terminaron el trabajo y el reporta el tiempo de cada uno, en pocas palabras los trabajadores no usan la aplicacion

Comment: Igualmente puedes usar variables de sesión, que aguantan mientras no cierres la página, da igual que actualices. Cuando una persona entra, el reportador le ticke (marque) la entrada con un ID asociado a ese trabajador y quede registrado en una variable de sesión. A la salida, lo mismo y si crees necesario, que se guarde en una BBDD.

Comment: Es para reportar diferentes actividades en el dia, no es jornada laboral

Comment: Yo personalmente y tal como lo planteas, utilizaría variables de sesión.

Comment: muestreme un ejemplo de como funcionaria y podria abrir mi proyecto que lo subi en el enlace al principio